# Creating a reference to another object

Tags: c#

I want to make an object that stores a reference to another object. I have a code like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int test = 1;
    store st;       

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        st = new store(test);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test = 7;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString((int)st.o);
    }
}

public class store
{
    public object o;

    public store(object obj)
    {
        o = obj;
    }
}
```

If I click button2 - I can see "1" in my label. But if I click button2 and then button1 - I still see "1". How should I alter my code so I'll see "7" in that case?

Comment: An `int` is a struct. Structs are passed by _value_, and not by _reference_ as classes are.

Comment: If you want changes to a variable (better: Property) to be reflected immediately you want to look into Data Binding. Also your integer is passed as a value to your store class, changing the reference in your main class isn't going to update it.

Comment: @Cyral Whether he has a value or a reference type is irrelivant here.  His store is only ever storing the value of the variable at the time of constructor, rather than hold onto a reference to the *variable* so that it can evaluate the value of the variable later.  Using a reference type instead of a value type wouldn't affect this program at all.  (You can change the `int` to a `string` and see for yourself, if you want.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the `store` object you're evaluating the *value* of the `test` variable, and storing *that value* rather than *the test variable*.  If you want to have a way of evaluating the variable to its value later, you can use a lambda to close over the variable, since closures in C# close over *variables*, not *values*.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int test = 1;
    Store<string> store;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        store = new Store<string>(() => test.ToString());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test = 7;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = store.GetValue();
    }
}

public class Store<T>
{
    private Func<T> function;

    public Store(Func<T> function)
    {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public T GetValue()
    {
        return function();
    }
}
```

Note that I made a few changes to the names of items to be in line with standard C# conventions, rather than having `Store` expose the generator function's field publicly, I provide a function that lets you get the value, and I've also made it generic, rather than using `object`, as this both avoids boxing, and prevents the need to cast the object returned from the store.

Comment: I'm trying to make this work for another class, for example, `Rectangle`:   st = new Store<Rectangle>(test);  causes an "Can't convert" error.

Comment: Added a comment instead of new line, sorry.

Comment: @AndrewR Take a look at how I'm constructing the `Store` in the answer.  Mirror that pattern.  You're passing the value, not a lambda that returns the value.

Comment: Thank, now it works. Never seen this construction before. What does () =>  construction mean?

Comment: @AndrewR It's a lambda, just like I said in my answer.

Comment: And one more question:
If I want to use `function` _value_ inside `Store` methods, for example, serialize it like:
Formatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
f.Serialize(SomeStream, _functionValue_);
Is it possible?

Comment: @AndrewR You're not going to be able to serialize it, no.  The variable that it's referencing *won't exist* once the application ends.

Answer (score -1):

With minimal changes, here you go.
Properties and constructor of Form1:

```
public Form1()
{
    st = new store(test);
}
private int testPrivate { get; set; }

public int test
{
    get { return testPrivate; }
    set
    {
        testPrivate = value;
        st.o = value;
    }
}

public store st { get; set; }
```

The store class:

```
public class store
{
    public object o { get; set; }

    public store(object obj)
    {
        o = obj;
    }
}
```